# Using huggingface fill-mask pipeline to get the "score" for a result it didn't suggest

Tags: python, neural-network, nlp, huggingface-transformers, spacy-transformers

I've been using huggingface to make predictions for masked tokens and it works great. I noticed that for each prediction it gives a "score" and would like to be given the "score" for some tokens that it did not predict but that I provide.

For example, if my sentence is `"I ate bacon and <mask> for breakfast"` I can use `pipeline('fill-mask')` to get back predictions and their scores e.g. it might give me back ["eggs", 0.1].  But what I would like to do is provide my own guess and then get back the score it assigns to my own guess. e.g. i might want to know what score it gives to the word "pancakes" in the situation.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use targets for this.

```
pipe = pipeline('fill-mask', model = model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
result = pipe('I ate bacon and <mask> for breakfast', targets= ['milk'])
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use bert-as-service for this task.
Refer this [library](https://github.com/Qordobacode/fitbert).

You can also use fill_mask() method
Refer this [link](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/master/examples/roberta/README.md)